# Is this PDE $u_t+u_{xxxx}+\sqrt{1+u}=0$ nonlinear homogeneous?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the PDE 
\begin{gather*}\tag{1}
u_t+u_{xxxx}+\sqrt{1+u}=0,
\end{gather*}
where $u=u(x,t),$ 
which occurs in Page 5 of  Strauss's book of PDE. I am wondering if it is homogeneous. Nonlinearity of this PDE is apparent. How can I determine if a given PDE is homogeneous, especially it is nonlinear?  What is the formal definition of homogeneous PDE, no matter what it is linear, or nonlinear? How about this PDE
\begin{gather*}\tag{2}
u_t+u_{xxxx}+\sqrt{x^2+t^2+u}=0,
\end{gather*}
whether it is homogeneous, or inhomogeneous?

Answer (score 0):

The point of homogeneity, if you're not considering linear problems necessarily, is not simply "you can put everything involving the solution on one side and the other side is zero". The point of homogeneity is that any multiple of a solution is a solution. This does not hold for either of those equations.

Comment: You mean that homogeneity is just the homogeneity of the corresponding partial differential operator, that is, let $L$ be a partial differential operator (not necessarily linear). If $L(\lambda u)=\lambda L(u),$ then $L(u)=0$ is homogeneous.  But Hanna said (in book  "Fourier series, transforms, and boundary value problems") that the differential equation $y''(x)+\sin(y(x))=0$ is nonlinear homogeneous!

Comment: @azc I guess you could define the term that way. You should be careful about how particular authors use general terms. That said, in the sense of that second definition, your first equation is clearly "nonlinear homogeneous". To me I would prefer to say (nonlinear) autonomous, though...

Comment: And so, according to your opinion, (2) is a nonlinear nonautonomous PDE. Thanks a lot, I've got it.